# Import CSV by name into google sheets

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, google-sheets, attachment

I have been using the following function to load CSV attachments into google sheets:

```
function importCSVFromGmail() {
var threads = GmailApp.search("from:cbuffone123@gmail.com");
var message = threads[0].getMessages()[0];
var attachment = message.getAttachments()[0];

// Is the attachment a CSV file
if (attachment.getContentType() === "text/csv") {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(attachment.getDataAsString(), ",");

    // Remember to clear the content of the sheet before importing new data
    sheet.clearContents().clearFormats();
    sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
}
}
```

the function currently gets ANY attachment sent from that email. I would like to alter the function so that it ONLY select attachments named "data.CSV" and ignores all other attachments. Is there a way to do this?

thank you in advance!

so i have modified this to :

```
function Exact_CSV_Import() {
    var threads = GmailApp.search("from:cbuffone123@gmail.com");
    var message = threads[0].getMessages()[0];
    var attachment = message.getAttachments()[0];  
    for (var n = 0; n < attachment.length; n++) {
var attachmentName = attachments[n].getName();
if (attachmentName = "data1.csv")  
{
    // do stuff with "data1.csv"        
     attachment.setContentTypeFromExtension();  
  if (attachment.getContentType() === "text/csv") {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(attachment.getDataAsString(), ",");
    sheet.clearContents().clearFormats();
    sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
}
}
```

}
}

and nothing seems to happen. i dont get any errors, but it doesnt seem to be doing anything?

Answer (score 0):

This statement:

```
var attachment = message.getAttachments()[0];
```

only looks at the first attachment in the array of attachments returned by `.getAttachments()`

Instead use `var attachments = message.getAttachments();`

Then you can loop through the attachments and pick the one you want.

This loop will print out the names of the attachments and their size;

```
for (var n = 0; n < attachments.length; n++) {
  Logger.log( attachments[n].getName(), attachments[n].getSize());
}
```

You should be able to proceed from there...

EDIT: Some more clarification to selectively process different CSV files as requested..

I'm pretty sure `attachments` is not an associative array so you cant do something like attachments["csv"]. But you can iterate through the list of attachments and pick out the ones with names that you want and ignore the rest. See below for some code...

```
for (var n = 0; n < attachments.length; n++) {

    var attachmentName = attachments[n].getName();

    if (attachmentName = "data1.csv")  
    {
        // do stuff with "data1.csv"
    }
    else
    if ((attachmentName = "data2.csv")
    { 
        // do stuff with "data1.csv"
    }
    else 
    {   
        // do nothing - just skip it
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for this...but i already know the name of the attachment. i want "data.csv" to go to google sheet A, and "data2.csv" to go to google sheet B.

Comment: am i able to specify the attachment i want to get? something like var attachment = message.getAttachment('data.csv')[0] ?

Comment: See edited post. Hopefully this clarifies a bit more but if not keep asking!

Comment: so i attempted to modify my original app, to include your suggestions. basically i want it to import the data if it is called data1.csv and ignore it and do nothing for all other attachments. but it doesnt seem to do anything when i run it

Comment: Ok why not make a copy of your sheet and send me a link so I can take a look.